# Vertical-align: middle for an object floated from left to the right

Tags: html, css, floating

1st: I think, like everyone, I love this page! Normally I can find everything here. Bu not this time. So I'll ask by myself.

**HTML**

```
<div>
<div class="img-wrap">
   <figure>
        <img src="http://www.porcelaingres.de/img/prodotti/collezioni/just_grey_dark_grey.jpg" style="">
   </figure>
</div>
<div class="text">
    <p>"Ich bin aus dem Dialogforum in der vergangenen Woche mit sehr viel Energie gegangen und werde die Themen meinen 20 Mitarbeitern unter anderem in unserer wöchentlichen Teamsitzung vermitteln."</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img-wrap {
    float: right; 
}

.img-wrap img {
    height: 320px; width: 320px; background: grey; border-radius: 50%;
}
```

I am trying to `vertical-align:middle` an **text next to an image**.

Until now, I already found the answer, but my problem is: 
The structure is not editable and the image is the first mentioned in the code, but floated to the right (`float:right`).

Until now, I couldn't find a way **without editing the structure**.

Could somebody help me?

**[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vuhynym8/1/)**

Comment: Even if you cannot change the HTML, you can still change the CSS. Just display the whole elements as inline-level elements (e.g. `inline-block`) and align them vertically to the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.text{
  height: 320px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vuhynym8/2/

Comment: Thanks first! I've got a fix height for the text, i could also use a `padding-top` to have it vertically centered. But the .text-height is variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this

CSS

```
.maindiv
    {
        float:right;
        text-align:right;
        width:80%;
    }
    .img-wrap {
        float: left; 
    }
    .img-wrap img {
        height: 320px; width: 320px; background: grey; border-radius: 50%;    
    }
    .text {
       float:left;
        width:30%;
       margin-top:100px;
        text-align:left;      
    }
```

and html

```
<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="img-wrap">
       <figure>
            <img src="http://www.porcelaingres.de/img/prodotti/collezioni/just_grey_dark_grey.jpg" style="">
       </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>"Ich bin aus dem Dialogforum in der vergangenen Woche mit sehr viel Energie gegangen und werde die Themen meinen 20 Mitarbeitern unter anderem in unserer wöchentlichen Teamsitzung vermitteln."</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[here is fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vuhynym8/3/)

Comment: Unfortunately, the text-length is variable. For this, a simple margin-top doesn't work here. But Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this markup structure can't be changed, then try to add this to your **CSS**.

```
.text {
    overflow: hidden;
    height:320px; /* Equal height as of image */
}
.text:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
.text p {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

View this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vuhynym8/5/)